# Meteor - Publish users based on startDate and endDate

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to publish all the users who have an active account between two date ranges. My code doesn't seem to be working, any thoughts?

```
Meteor.publish('classAuction', function (group) {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['is_teacher'], group)) {

    var users = Meteor.users.find({roles:'is_student', "accountStatus.isUserAccountActive": true}); // Get active candidates

    var today = new Date().toDateString();
    var startDate = Date(accountStatus.startDate).toDateString();


    if (today >= startDate) {
      return Meteor.users.find({});
    } else {

    // user not authorized. do not publish secrets
    this.stop();
    return;
  }
}
});
```

Comment: where did you get the profile ?

Comment: also, the query doesn't seem to query based on date?

Comment: OK. I've tried something else, still not working (see above). Am I any closer to getting this to work or am I nowhere near it.

Comment: What is `accountStatus`? Where did it appear?

Comment: Hi @BryukhanovValentin accountStatus is managed by admin. An 'active' account is an account where isUserAccountActive: true and where today's date is between the startDate and endDate.

Comment: Is it a package or global variable? And you said about two dates, but I don't see endDate

Comment: Ummm, collection2/SimpleSchema. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I've removed the endDate to try and simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mongo query for this, something like:

```
var today = new Date();

return Meteor.users.find({
    "accountStatus.startDate": { $gte: today},
    roles:'is_student',
    "accountStatus.isUserAccountActive": true
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Arcnon. I just tried this and it works. Thanks!